# Convert star name into entity value

Tags: curated-data, astronomy, entity

I have a list of star names:

```
stan = Select[#, Last[#] < Quantity[153.5, "LightYears"] &] &@
  StarData[StarData[], {"Name", "DistanceFromEarth"}]
```

generated 7882 stars.

```
stan2 = Take[ Sort[stan, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &], 91]
```

picked the ones that were one light year from the limit.

I transposed the list to get just the starnames.

```
stan3 = First[Transpose[stan2]]
```

Now I want to list the starname, Right Ascension, Declination.

```
StarData[StarData[stan3], {"RightAscension", "Declination", 
  "DistanceFromEarth"}]
```

but this generates the error:

```
StarData::notent: {{HIP 99969,\[Zeta] 1 Lyrae,HIP 77083,HIP 61505,HIP 22142,HIP 20492,HIP 2824,HIP 108859,\[Rho] Aquilae,HIP 99695,HIP 78923,HIP 67501,HIP 26563,HIP 25523,<<24>>,HIP 105906,HIP 77269,HIP 53106,HIP 35437,HIP 104351,HIP 96725,HIP 70677,HIP 52682,HIP 20850,\[Delta] 1 Tauri,HIP 4482,HIP 89000,<<41>>},<<1>>} is not a known entity, class, or tag for StarData. Use StarData[] for a list of entities. >>
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> will "discover" the name and turn it into an entity, but I can't `Map` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> onto a list.  I tried mapping `Entity["Star" #]&` onto the list but this did not work.  How do I get the starnames to act like `StarData` entities and not simply text?

Answer (score 2):

Load some example data

```
s1 = StarData[EntityClass["Star", "StarNearest10"]]
```

[image]

The necessary steps now are

```
s2 = StarData[s1, {"Name", "DistanceFromEarth"}];
s3 = Reverse@SortBy[Last][Select[s2, Last[#] < Quantity[5, "LightYears"] &]]
```

[image]

It's important to remove the spaces from the star names!

```
s4 = Map[Entity["Star", #] &, StringReplace[s3[[All, 1]], " " -> ""]]
```

[image]

```
StarData[s4, {"Name", "RightAscension", "Declination", "DistanceFromEarth"}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Comment: This procedure works with english characters, and fails when the star name has a greek letter.  {Entity["Star", "HIP99969"], Entity["Star", "\[Zeta]1Lyrae"], 
 Entity["Star", "HIP77083"], Entity["Star", "HIP61505"], 
 Entity["Star", "HIP22142"], Entity["Star", "HIP20492"], 
 Entity["Star", "HIP2824"], Entity["Star", "HIP108859"], 
 Entity["Star", "\[Rho]Aquilae"]}